# Directed Acyclic graph implementation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, graph, active-record

I have an implementation for a graph node class that I'd like to have function as a directed acyclic graph.

The associations are roughly as follows

```
class Node
  has_many :parents, 
           class_name: 'Edge',
           foreign_key: :child_id

  has_many :children,
           class_name: 'Edge',
           foreign_key: :parent_id
end

class Edge
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Node'
  belongs_to :child, class_name: 'Node'

  has_many :edge_properties
end
```

Me and a co-worker of mine had a discussion about the proper way to do this `has_many` relationship. The rails paradigm seems to dictate that `node.parents` should return a `Node::ActiveRecord_Relation`. However, in this case, `node.parents` returns a list of edges, which results the ask for the node's parents into something of the sort:

```
Node.where(id: Edge.where(child: node))
```

The question is; is this a code smell? Can we do this relationship better where `node.parents` would return `Node::ActiveRecord`? If so, how would one access `edge.edge_properties`?

Comment: `The rails paradigm seems to dictate that node.parents should return a Node::ActiveRecord_Relation`. This has nothing to do with the Rails paradigm, a has_many can return whatever you need.  `node.parents` should of course return nodes, not edges.  For that, create `node.incoming_edges`, `node.outgoing_edges` or similar.

Comment: Isn't what you said contradiction? Stating that it has nothing to do with the rails paradigm but then going on and saying that `should of course return nodes, not edges`?. I think we both can agree rails prefers a particular solution and that in itself is it's paradigm.

Comment: I meant that it's graph terminology. A parent/child of a node is another node, not an edge. At least, AFAIK, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the `through:` option of `has_many`:

```
class Node
  has_many :parent_edges, class_name: "Edge", foreign_key: :child_id
  has_many :parents, through: :parent_edges

  # ditto for children
end
```

Getting at edge_properties depends on the version of Rails you are using.

Comment: It seems that rails does not recognize the correct id on the edge class.
```
SELECT `nodes`.* 
FROM   `nodes` 
       INNER JOIN `edges` 
               ON `nodes`.`id` = 
                  `edges`.`parent_id` 
WHERE  `edges`.`node_id` = 16 
ORDER  BY `node`.`name` ASC 
```

Comment: @DavidZhang You almost certainly need to specify additional options. I don't know them off the top of my head but there is plenty of documentation out there.